# requirejs optimization error: Loader plugin did not call the load callback in the build: text

Tags: requirejs, r.js, requirejs-text

Using require.js with the requirejs api (r.js) for optimization/minification and needed to reorganize our directory structure (and, therefore, re-map everything in the requirejs config file/etc).

Result of attempting a compile (through node) is currently:

```
compiling js...<br />
/usr/local/www/site/build/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:14174<br />
            throw new Error(errorMsg);<br />
                  ^
**Error: Error: Loader plugin did not call the load callback in the build: text**<br />
Module loading did not complete for: <br />
at Function.build.traceDependencies (/usr/local/www/site/build/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:15178:19)<br />

at build (/usr/local/www/site/build/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:14174:23)<br />
at requirejs.optimize.runBuild (/usr/local/www/site/build/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:15472:30)<br />
at Object.context.execCb (/usr/local/www/site/build/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1692:33)<br />
at Object.Module.check (/usr/local/www/site/build/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:948:51)<br />
at Object.Module.enable.id (/usr/local/www/site/build/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1181:34)<br />
at g (/usr/local/www/site/build/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:233:23)<br />
at Module.emit (/usr/local/www/site/build/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1224:21)<br />
at each (/usr/local/www/site/build/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:165:31)<br />
at Object.Module.emit (/usr/local/www/site/build/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1223:17)<br />
at Object.Module.check (/usr/local/www/site/build/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js:1002:30)<br />
```

Build call is:

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

var config = {
    baseUrl: './public/js',
    mainConfigFile: './public/js/config/config.js',
    paths: {
         'requireLib': 'library/require'
    },
    out: "./public/js/minified/main.js",
    name: "minified/main",
    wrap: false,
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    deps: ["../js/local/main","modules/movie","modules/theatre"]
};

requirejs.optimize(config);
```

Config file is:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        // JavaScript folders
        libs: "library",
        plugins: "plugin",
        adminlibs: "../adminassets/js/plugins/ui",

        // Libraries
        jquery: "library/jquery",
        jqcookie: "library/jquery.cookie",
        jqui: "../adminassets/js/plugins/ui/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min",
        jqezmark: "library/jquery.ezmark",
        jqcolor: "library/jquery.color",
        underscore: "library/underscore-amdjs",
        backbone: "library/backbone-amdjs",
        chosen: "library/chosen.jquery",
        moment: "library/moment",

        // Plugins
        text: "plugin/text", 
        async: "plugin/async",
        datetimepicker: "../adminassets/js/plugins/ui/jquery.datetimepicker",
        ajaxfileupload: "../adminassets/js/plugins/uploader/jquery.ajaxfileupload"
    },

    shim: {
        'chosen': ['jquery'],
        'jqcookie': ['jquery'],
        'jqui': ['jquery'],
        'jqezmark': ['jquery'],
        'jqcolor': ['jquery'],
        'jquifull' : ['jquery'],
        'datetimepicker' : ['jqui'],
        'ajaxfileupload' : ['jquery'],
        'backbone': ['underscore','jquery']
    },

    // Initialize the application with the main application file
    deps: ["local/main"]
});
```

Not really sure what's wrong here.  The entire setup was working until I started moving files around ... but the compile process still finds all the files it needs ... it just hits the callback error listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that updating my requirejs, text plugin, and r.js files resolved the issue.